# How to create flat circular spiral made from quads?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

[image: image used to show the approximate mesh i want]

I have been trying to create a specific mesh, the picture showcased is the closest image i have found to demonstrate the mesh i want, basically a flat circular spiral made out of quads, with the gaps (colourful areas in picture) also being filled with similar quads. And of course all the quads must be joined together, so i can't use the array modifier. If anything is unclear, please say so, i realize this image is not optimal, and i am happy to clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42674 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79764 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111337 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253

Comment: yes, those adress various spirals, but none of them adress my specific problem, Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

With your description, cubes with inset Faces, an Array modifier and a curve modifier is a good option. you might need to explain a bit more about your final goal.
[image]

using a cube with inset faces, adding an array modifier and curves modifier, then, inside the curves modifier you need to add an Archemedial Spiral (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Curves > Spiral >Archemedial)